# Is there a way to run a separate looping worker process that references a Django app's models?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, heroku

I have a webapp that monitors sites that users add for any changes. To do this, I need to have some sort of separate background thread/process that is constantly iterating through the list of sites, pinging them one at a time, and emailing any users that are monitoring a site that changes. I am currently using a thread that I initialize at the end of my urls.py file. This works fine with Django's development server, but it begins to break down once I deploy it to Heroku with Gunicorn. As soon as there are multiple connections, multiple copies of the worker thread get started, as Gunicorn starts more worker threads to handle the concurrent connections (at least, this is what I think is the reason behind the extra threads is). This causes duplicate emails to be sent out, one from each thread.

I am now trying to find another means of spawning this worker thread/process. I saw a similar inquiry [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323252/is-there-a-way-to-control-a-looping-python-script-with-heroku), but when I tried the posted solution, I was unable to reference the models from my Django app and received this error message when I tried to do so:

`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

I have also tried using `django-background-tasks`, which is frequently recommended as a simple solution for issues like this. However, it doesn't seem suited for looping, continuous processes. The same goes for Celery and other solutions like it. I am just looking for a way to start a separate worker Dyno that continuously runs in the background, without a queue or anything like that, and is able to use the models from my Django app to create QuerySets that can be iterated through. What would be the best way to do something like this? Please let me know if any more information would help.

Comment: A celerybeat task could accomplish this. Why do you think it’s not suitable?

Comment: To my (admittedly somewhat limited) understanding, a Celery periodic task or a repeating `django-background-tasks` task would run at set times each day, like a crontab. However, I am trying to constantly be pinging sites with no delay between cycles (ie iterate through the QuerySet of all of the sites, refresh the QuerySet, and do it again). Additionally, since the number of sites can change, running the task at some constant interval wouldn't work. However, I could be misunderstanding the Celery documentation. My apologies if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try editing the code so that the parts that handle the email specifically aren't tried so intrinsically to the django model, such that both the django model and this secondary application interact with the standard python class/module/object/etc, instead of trying to graft out the part of django you need elsewhere.

Alternatively, you can try using something like [threading.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) if your app is actually using threads inside one interpreter to prevent multiple messages from sending. There is also a [multiprocessing.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) that may work if the threading one does not.

Another option would be to make it so each requested change would have a unique value to it, preferably something based on the contents of the changes themselves. IE if you have something like:

```
def check_send_email(email_addr, website_url, text_that_changed):
    database.query('INSERT INTO website_updates VALUES %s, %s', (website_url, text_that_changed,))

    if (database.check_result()):  # update was not already present in database
        send_email(email_addr)

check_send_email('email@example.com', 'website.com', '<div id="watched-div">')
```

obviously you'd need to interact with some more concrete tools, but the general idea above is that if requests come in, you don't send multiple emails needlessly. Of course, finding a value you can always generate exactly the same given a specific change, but is also unique every time may prove difficult.